# get list item from SharePoint online 365 using rest api

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, ajax

I need to get data from SharePoint online list by using rest api. I will use the `GET` and `POST` method (post method in camel query case).

`urlapp`: the encoded url such as `https://name-29a8f2a9e3342d....`

```
$.ajax({
   url: urlapp + "/../_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Letters')",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
    },
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);//Debug statement                 
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

the previous code generate the `403 (Forbidden) error`.

After searching I found solution by using `executeAsyn (new SP.RequestExecutor)`, but I need some way is sync execution not async.

Comment: Is this a 365 tenant farm or a 365 dedicated farm?

Comment: Navigate to url value. If it returns any results, then you shouldn't be getting any errors.

Comment: I dont think you need sync code, you can do the next operations in the async success callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `.done()` method to achieve your synchronous effect on your calls.

For Example:

```
function AjaxCall(url) {
var call = $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
return call;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
var firstCall = AjaxCall(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Letters')/items");
firstCall.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    $.each(data.d.results, function(i, val) {
       //doSomething
    });
    var secondCall = AjaxCall(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('newList')/items");
    secondCall.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $.each(data.d.results, function(i, val) {
           //doSomething
        });
    });
});
```

This will help you achieve synchronous effect with asynchronous calls..

Comment: thank you for response but if i put any code after done calling will execute before finish the done calling and I can not insert all the code inside done

Comment: You can write function and call that function inside done

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code.

```
 var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor('AppWebURL');
     executor.executeAsync(
                {
                    url: "AppWebURL" + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Letters')/Items?@target='HostWebURL'",
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log('success');
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        console.log("error");
                    }
                });
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Sorry for that but this solution is async and I have to use the rest api with online sharepoint

Comment: It is not possible to do sync call while access data from host web from app web.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery Deffered for this.

Sample Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function testCreateFolder() {
        CreateFoldersbyparent("abc", "MyDoc/").done(function () {
            CreateFoldersbyparent("test", "MyDoc/abc/");
        })
    }

    function CreateFoldersbyparent(name, parent, callback) {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        // replace below with your logic
        var documentLibraryName = "MyDoc";
        var fileCollectionEndpoint = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('" + documentLibraryName + "')/folders/add('" + parent + name + "')";
        $.ajax({
            url: fileCollectionEndpoint,
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            headers: {
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("done");
                deferred.resolve(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //handle error...
                console.log(jqXHR);
            }
        });
        return deferred.promise();
    }
</script>
```